# Android pop fragment from backstack with animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have an activity that loads a Fragment A in it. Fragment A contains ListView and when clicking on list item I load another Fragment B in place of Fragment A to show the listview item details. On button click and pressing device back button I it loads the previous fragment which is Fragment A that shows ListView. All this is working fine but I want to load Fragment A with animation on backpress or on button click. I am doing it in this way but not working:

```
   FragmentManager fsm = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ftransaction = fsm.beginTransaction();                   
   ftransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.enter_from_left);        
   fsm.popBackStack();
   ftransaction.commit();

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
     android:duration="700"
     android:fromXDelta="-100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%"
     android:toXDelta="0%"
     android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="false" >

  <translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want backstack animations you'll need to use:

[setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Something like:

```
setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.enter_from_left,
        R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.exit_to_left);
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, 
                               android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 
                               R.anim.slide_in_right,
                               R.anim.slide_out_left);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, targetFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

this line

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 
                       R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

would create perfect animation.

**slide_in_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

With navigation component is very easy too:

```
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
```