# addToBackstack not working when replacing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having an issue where I call `addToBackStack` on my fragment when replacing it, but when I press back to go back to that fragment, it doesn't go back, it just closes my app.

```
Fragment fragmentWebView = new MyWebView();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentWebView);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.commit();
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? everything looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this code to your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

[Watched here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600434/2260775)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's related but you shouldn't create your fragment using `new`, see [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You should call addToBackStack(MyWebView.class.getName()); and it is recommended that you check if your fragment exist. The complet transaction could be something like this:

```
Fragment fragmentWebView = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyWebView.class.getName());
if (fragmentWebView == null)
     fragmentWebView = new MyWebView();

transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentWebView, MyWebView.class.getName());
transaction.addToBackStack(MyWebView.class.getName());
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.commit();
```

Now, you can identify your fragment by a tag (MyWebView.class.getName()). Hope it helps you!!